# Unable to see App Launcher navigation item or App Launcher inside App Launcher Lightning App

Tags: lightning, app, app-launcher

When users log into Salesforce, I want their default `App` to display the `App Launcher`.

To try and achieve this, I have created an `Lightning App` called `Company Name`

And I've added the `App Launcher` navigation item (see below), so that, by default, users are greeted with the App Launcher when they first login.

[image: App Launcher navigation item selected]

And I have created a `Permission Set` with the `Use Identity Features` permission enabled, and added everyone to the permission set.

Yet, when I open the App called `Company Name`, I cannot see the Apps and there are no navigation tabs in the main menu:

[image]

I would like to see the App Launcher displayed as a page.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93485/discussion-on-question-by-robs-unable-to-see-app-launcher-navigation-item-or-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to raise a case with Salesforce the their `Feature Activations Team` has to enable something to make this work.

Answer (score -2):

could you please cross check your profile APP settings for which you enabled "user identity feature". App launcher should display all app's where permission is already enabled. Please have a look into below screen shot.
[image: profile app setting]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, unfortunately you didn't fully understand the question. I can still open the App Launcher by press the nine dots. But I want the App Launcher page to be displayed by default when a user logs in.

Comment: Please delete your answer